# React setState doesnt update state while changing an image

Tags: reactjs, setstate

In a product detail page I got a big picture of an item and a few small pictures inside a carousel. I 'm tryin to replace the big picture with the small ones if they get clicked.

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        zoomProps: {
            width: 400,
            zoomWidth:500,
            scale:1.5,
            img:'assets/images/products/14.jpg',
            offset: {vertical: 0, horizontal: 10},
        }
    }
}

handleClick(i){
    this.setState({
        zoomProps:{
            img: i,
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using zoomProps state like this and it works fine;

```
<div  style={{display: 'flex', marginBottom: 10}}>
      <ReactImageZoom  {...this.state.zoomProps}  />
</div>
```

And I'm tryin to setState zoomProps img's address like this;

```
 <a className="horizontal-thumb active" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null,`'assets/images/products/17.jpg'`)} >
 <img  className="img-responsive" width="85" alt="None" src="assets/images/products/5.jpg" data-echo="assets/images/products/17.jpg" />
</a>
```

But it gives me this error;

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of nullhandleClick
C:/Users/kalen/WebstormProjects/emlakui/src/components/detail/detail_partials/content.js:20
  17 |    }
  18 | 
  19 |    handleClick(i){
> 20 |        this.setState({
  21 |            zoomProps:{
  22 |                img: i,
  23 |            }
```

If console.log(i) in handleClick function that I see it's passing the correct data but for some reason zoomProps' img state doesn't get updated.
Can anyone please show me the correct way to this right?
Another question : Do I have to use redux and create some actions for it ?

Edit: In the other read property 'setState' of undefined answer doesnt include

onClick={this.handleClick.**bind(this,'assets/images/products/17.jpg')**} . I was tryin to send data like this so these are similar but different questions I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `context` of `handleClick` as `null` , that should be `this` , means ref to current component.

Change this :

```
this.handleClick.bind(null,`'assets/images/products/17.jpg'`)
```

to

```
this.handleClick.bind(this,'assets/images/products/17.jpg')
```

Comment: I changed to this.handleClick.bind(this,`'assets/images/products/17.jpg'`) and now if I click the small pic, big pic disappears. I think I'm making some other mistakes here too..

Comment: please check updated answer , remove ` from image url